# Uppercase input turns on periodically

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have some problem. Every 3-5 second everything, that I input from keyboard became **UPPERCASE** only. I also have two keyboard layouts: **us** and **ua**. And when uppercase happens - I can't switch my keyboard layout (I use mod4 for switching).

This is my xmodmap output:

```
$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 3 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

I tried `xmodmap -e "clear lock"`, but uppercase input still periodically turns on. I tried to disable Caps Lock key in "hardware way", putting insulator between keyboard contacts. But I doesn't help.

*== Update ==* For **A#1**
Look, there is sticky Caps_Lock:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
    root 0xaa, subw 0x0, time 30893676, (-254,229), root:(384,359),
    state 0x2, keycode 39 (keysym 0x53, S), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (53) "S"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (53) "S"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What I'm doing? **First**, I run `florence` (Virtual Keyoards) and turn off Caps_Lock key. **Second**, I type: `xmodmap -e "clear lock"`. But it is very dirty hack :), you know. It works for few minutes or few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I plugged in USB keyboard. In GRUB menu I added into **kernel** string: `i8042.nokbd` (after `quiet`).

Also, if you need to turn-off notebook keyboard while working, use **xinput**.

- First execute `xinput list`, than find line with `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard`.
- Then `xinput list-props 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'` or using id (14 for example) `xinput list-props 14`.
- Find `Device Enabled` and `xinput set-prop 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard' 'Device Enabled' 0` or using id `xinput set-prop 14 134 0`.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are that your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is getting stuck. Try pressing and releasing your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (both, if you have a left and a right key). This is most likely to be a hardware issue if you haven't noticed other keys getting stuck.

When the problem happens, run `xterm -e xev` (you might want to have an icon or menu entry ready so that you can launch `xev` with only mouse clicks). When you press a key in the `xev` window, you'll see output like

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xa5, subw 0x0, time 201838723, (221,316), root:(232,403),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

`state 0x0` means that there is no modifier. With a `Shift` modifier down, you'd see `state 0x1`. The `Lock` (a.k.a. Caps Lock) modifier is `state 0x2`; more generally, with several modifiers down, you'll see a bitwise mask of the modifiers (e.g. `state 0x5` if you have both `Shift` (1) and `Ctrl` (4) down). If the problem persists, tell us how the `xev` output deviates from what you expect.